# Exact solution to $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 1 + \frac{a}{y} + \frac{b}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

This equation arises from my attempt to study the quasi-steady state of a cross-diffusive system.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1 + \frac{a}{y} + \frac{b}{x},$$
where $2>a > 1> b > 0$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

I learned that it is a special case of the Chini equation, which typically does not have a closed form solution. But it looks so simply to not have a closed form solution! On the other hand, I have tried many different methods and substitution to try to obtain its closed form in vain.

Could someone please help suggest a way to do this?

Comment: `quasi-steady state of a cross-diffusive system` That's a fancy name.Now I'll also use it !

Comment: If you're interested, the original system comes from Sherratt, Jonathan A., and Mark AJ Chaplain. "A new mathematical model for avascular tumour growth." Journal of mathematical biology 43.4 (2001): 291-312. I modified it a bit though.

Comment: @Paichu: This is a Chini Equation and you might want to read this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41177/a-particularly-hard-nonlinear-first-order-ordinary-differential-equation

Comment: Thank you. I am checking out that post.

Comment: @Moo The Chini Invariance $C$ in my case is not independent of $t$. And I can't read German. :(

Comment: You are JUST constant for all $t$, clear? Does not change the fact that this is a Chini's equation. Well, at least now you have something to research! Also, did you look through the Equation World link to see if this form is included? If not - numerical methods are likely your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1+\dfrac{a}{y}+\dfrac{b}{x}$

$y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\left(1+\dfrac{b}{x}\right)y+a$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.